# Any way to get back the view where I can see all currently installed NPM package versions and which are outdated?

Tags: macos, webstorm

Previously there was a view to look at your NPM package versions and see which ones are outdated. This help overview all dependencies at once, not by clicking on-by-one on package.json file which works fine now.

Is there a way to get this view with current version of WebStorm? Was this view removed for some reason?

The menu title in Settings is updated too from "Node.js and NPM" to just "Node.js"

Can't find any info related to this view. Is there any way to get it back?

Closest solution to this view i find is this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get this view with current version of WebStorm?

Accordingly to WebStorm help pages that functionality has been **removed since 2022.1** version. The last version that has manage packages mentioned for that settings screen is 2021.3 ([the help page for that version](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/node-js.html)).

---

> Was this view removed for some reason?

Yes. From the corresponding ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43624

> We believe that the package.json file is the main entry point for the tasks related to the management of the project dependencies...

*(check the ticket for more details)*

Such package management should now be done via your `package.json` file (the usual <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> / light bulb icon Intentions menu). Or you can do it manually in your terminal (`npm outdated` if I'm not mistaken)

This is what the Help page says: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/installing-and-removing-external-software-using-node-package-manager.html#ws_npm_pnpm_yarn_install_and_upgrade_packages_from_package_json